# Azure SQL - Create view with query through multiple databases

Tags: sql-server, azure, view

I have two different databases and I need information from both DB's. I managed to get the data like this:

```
create master key encryption by password = 'test'

create database scoped crendetial testcredentials with identity = 'secret@login', secret = 'secret@password'

-- CREATE DATA SOURCE --
create external data source RemoteDataSource with
(
    type = RDBMS,
    location = 'secret.database.windows.net',
    database_name = 'testDB_Dev',
    credential = testcredentials
)

-- CREATE TABLES --
create external table [RemoteDepartment]
(
    [ID] [int],
    [Name] [nvarchar](50)
)
with
(
    data_source = RemoteDataSource,
    schema_name = 'dbo',
    object_name = 'Department'
);
```

From here I can now `select`, `join`, and much more. (*Employee table comes from the other DB (the one I'm querying)*)

```
select e.Name, e.Role, d.Name from Employee as e inner join
    RemoteDepartment as d on d.ID = e.DepartmentId
```

With the following output

```
|---Name---|---Role---|---Name--|
|  Louise  |  Manager |    HR   |
|    Tim   | Finances |  Admin  |
```

Here's is my problem. While this is all working very nice and fast, I can't seem to wrap my head around, or find any resources online, on how to create views using this method of querying two seperate DB's.

I have tried the following:

```
create master key encryption by password = 'test'

create database scoped crendetial testcredentials with identity = 'secret@login', secret = 'secret@password'

-- CREATE DATA SOURCE --
create external data source RemoteDataSource with
(
    type = RDBMS,
    location = 'secret.database.windows.net',
    database_name = 'testDB_Dev',
    credential = testcredentials
)

-- CREATE TABLES --
create external table [RemoteDepartment]
(
    [ID] [int],
    [Name] [nvarchar](50)
)
with
(
    data_source = RemoteDataSource,
    schema_name = 'dbo',
    object_name = 'Department'
);

CREATE VIEW test_view AS
    select e.Name, e.Role, d.Name from RemoteEmployee as e inner join
        RemoteDepartment as d on d.ID = e.DepartmentId
```

But getting a compile error saying

> Incorrect syntax: 'CREATE VIEW' must be the only statement in the batch

I tried removing everything except the `select` statement, but this doesn't work (*the compiler has no idea what `RemoteDepartment` actually is*)

Comment: Sorry, you say that you have two different databases, but I only see 2 tables in one database `testDB_Dev`

Comment: Yes of course. I made an edit to the post. The table `Employee` comes from the db being queried. My apologies

Comment: I suggest you create the 2 tables in one database, otherwise, using 2 databases waste too much resource

Comment: I am very aware of this, but I cannot change the architecture. Me and my team already have loads of services running on these DBs, and we cannot take the time to change the architecture. I'm aware that the architecture is strange (I didn't create this mess) but this is not what this question is about. I appreciate your comment though.

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like just a simple case of not being able to do cross database queries with an Azure SQL DB instance.

Comment: But I can though? Did you read what I wrote? I can get the data, I just can't create a view.